# Setting State messes with Promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

Pardon me, this will be a little more awkwardly worded as I try to explain my exact issue.

I have a function that I return a promise from. I do that because I have to use some async code, and want to make sure I am returning the correct boolean value

I use:

```
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
```

to either resolve or reject the promise based off of what I find in the loop that I go through..
This is then how I call that particular function.. in which I name "testFunction"

```
testFunction()
            .then(function() { alert('Yes'); 

            })
            .catch(function() { alert('No'); 
            });
```

This all works fine.. if it resolves it alerts Yes, if it does not it alerts No...

However, I need to somehow store the results of this so I attempted to do so like this using the state:

```
testFunction()
            .then(function() { alert('Yes'); 
              this.setState({
                 value: true
              })

            })
            .catch(function() { alert('No'); 
            });
```

Basically just simply setting the state with true if the promise resolves. **However** when I do that the .catch function is also run as if the promise did not resolve.

I am assuming this is some sort of property of the state? I can't really figure out the reason why this would work like this. Is there a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Your first mistake is that you're using `this.setState` inside a non-arrow function. `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: what do you expect `this` to be, what object are you trying to run `setState` on - your code as is, `this` would either be undefined or the `window` object - neither of which have the `setState` method, if you change your catch to `.catch(function(e) { console.log(e); });` you should see what the error is in your browsers developer tools console

Comment: @JaromandaX this is tagged `react-native` so I assume a React component

Comment: @AR7 - assumptions are good, I was asking the OP because only he would know not only a vague description like "a React component", he would know the exact object he wants it to be :p

Answer (score 0):

@FuzzyTree is right. I just wanted to add that you can also you arrow functions which never bind their execution context:

```
testFunction()
.then(() => { 
    alert('Yes'); 
    this.setState({value: true});
}).catch(() => { 
    alert('No');
});
```

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions and they can not be used as constructors.

You can read more about arrow function in [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)